# Does an XT rear shifter fit a GRX RD (both 11-speed, mechanical)?

Tags: shimano, shifting, grx

Gravel bike specs:

• Shimano XT 2x11 shifters, mechanical
• Shimano GRX FD & RD, 11-speed/mech
• 105 crankset, 50-34

The rear shifting is not smooth, especially when I transition to the 4th gear. It jumps to the 5th gear, but feels smooth with the other cogs.

What can I do to make the shifting smooth? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no compatibility between any Shimano road 11 front or rear derailleur and any Shimano mountain shifter.

Use one of the flat bar road 2x11 sets such as SL-RS700.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your input, sir. Much appreciated.